# Html menu, last button on right side

Tags: html, css

Im creating simple website for friend but i have no idea how to to align last **li** element to right, when everything is forced to left side.
Here is what i actually have, i was trying to add custom ID/Class to last li and tried to float:right but doesnt work. Im lost in this so hard

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    #wrap{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#top{
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
}

#menu ul{
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-left: -40px;


}
#menu li a{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right:12px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    background-color:#123e90;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;

}

#menu li a:hover{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right:12px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    background-color:#1c5cd2;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fhs6m2cy/

Comment: what do you mean when you say align right ?

Comment: I have aligned all li elements on left side, but i want one on right side. 
this http://prntscr.com/61coex

Comment: Paulie_D answer will be perfect then!

Comment: On a side note the reason your float right was not working was because you have float left overwriting it ion your `#menu li{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `last-child` option

```css
#wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
#top {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
}
#menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
#menu li:last-child {
  float: right;
}
#menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #123e90;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#menu li a:hover {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #1c5cd2;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="top">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Media</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```